# Compilation error: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:elevation'

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Why do I get the following error when trying to build App in Xamarin and how can it be resolved?

> No resource found that matches the given name: `attr android:elevation`

I would also like to mention that the above error has occurred after I wrote the code to add map into my app.

Comment: Which compileSdkVersion ("Compile using Android-Version:") did you specifed in your project-properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compileSdkVersion is invalid. A **minimum SDK-Version** of **21** is required for `android:elevation`.

Right click on your Android-Project inside Visual Studio and change the selected android-version ("Compile using Android-Version"). Clean your project and build it again. The error should disappear.

If there is no entry for API Level 21 or higher then you have to download the appropriate SDK-Levels in the Android SDK Manager.

[image: Project Settings]

Comment: That is all well and good but what if you want to compile using an old SDK,

I need to use 4.3 and even if i remove those lines, Xamarin keeps putting them back in...

Comment: I face the same problem. Althought the Project does not use elevation anywhere it get's created during the build